# python question :sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor

Tags: python, database

I wrote a database-select function

```
def select_data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "select VC_FUNDCODE from data_ds limit 100;"
    fund_list = cur.execute(sql)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return fund_list    

fund_list = select_data()
datalist = []
for item in fund_list:
    datalist.append(item)
print(datalist)
```

Interpreter returns a traceback when i try to call it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/chinalife/Desktop/source/flaskTiantian/database.py", line 70, in 
> for item in fund_list:
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor.

Comment: You are closing the cursor before it's result is received. This happens when you iterate over it, not when you run `execute()`.

Comment: Okay, see where the error message talks about a "closed cursor"? In your own words, what do you think a cursor is? What do you think it means to close it, and what effect do you think that should have? Where your code says `cur.close()`, why did you write it, and what do you think it does?

Comment: Thank you very much！I  was really inspired and got a resolution . besides, this is my first quest,  you guys are friendly to me , thanks again。

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, maybe this a simple problem, but I am so happy I could figure it out, here is my corrected code:

```
# 
def select_data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "select VC_FUNDCODE from data_ds limit 100;"
    fund_list = cur.execute(sql)
    datalist = []
    for item in fund_list:
        datalist.append(item)
    print(datalist)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return datalist

datalist = select_data()
print(datalist)
```